# How to override Entity class to add new option to dropdown-list of the import type? PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: import, overriding, backend, prestashop-1.7

I want to develop a module that will import products from a custom ***.svg** file, which is not among the sample files for import. To do this, I want to add another option for choosing the type of import in the drop-down menu "Type of import".
But this dropdown is building from the final class **src/Core/Import/Entity.php**, where all import types are hardcoded and defined using constants.

Am I correct in understanding that in order to achieve my goal, I must override this class, or it can be brought in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed in this case the file must be modified:
`src/Core/Import/File/FileUploader.php` at line 129:
replace

```
if (!preg_match('#([^\.]*?)\.(csv|xls[xt]?|o[dt]s)$#is', $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName())) {
```

through

```
if (!preg_match('#([^\.]*?)\.(svg|csv|xls[xt]?|o[dt]s)$#is', $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName())) {
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t understand me, sorry, I probably didn’t explain it well, it’s because of bad English. I'll try to explain it again. In the admin panel on the import page, the first step for import is to select the type of import. We do this by selecting one of the items in the drop-down menu. In this drop-down menu there are only 9 items, each of which corresponds to a specific **.svg** file which are presented in the examples. But so later I want to add another **.svg** file, for import, different from all the others. In order to be able to use the new file type for import, the user must be able to select the appropriate type in the drop-down list.Thus, at the first stage of solving my problem, I just need to add one more item to the drop-down list, which will correspond to the new type of import. But the problem is that this drop-down list is built on the basis of the final class **src/Core/Import/Entity.php** in which all types of imports are hard-coded through constants.

So my question is, should I override this class in order to add another type of import, or can this problem be solved in some other way?